# Chromecast Sleep/Background issue in iOS app

Tags: ios, chromecast, google-cast

I am facing a very big issue while using Chromecast in my application. I am using normal `GCKUICastButton` to connect to the Chromecast. The video plays well.

I am using the default Cast receiver for my application. When the device goes to sleep, sometimes, Chromecast stops and sometimes, after sleep mode, the device disconnects after some time. After going through lot of forums and Stack Overflow questions, I implemented the below code

```
extension GCKSessionManager {
static func ignoreAppBackgroundModeChange() {
    let oldMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(GCKSessionManager.self, #selector(GCKSessionManager.suspendSession(with:)))
    let newMethod = class_getInstanceMethod(GCKSessionManager.self, #selector(GCKSessionManager.suspendSessionIgnoringAppBackgrounded(with:)))
    method_exchangeImplementations(oldMethod, newMethod)

}

func suspendSessionIgnoringAppBackgrounded(with reason: GCKConnectionSuspendReason) -> Bool {
    guard reason != .appBackgrounded else { return false }
    return suspendSession(with:reason)
}
}
```

Then in my code I wrote the below line

```
GCKSessionManager.ignoreAppBackgroundModeChange()
```

Now suddenly, the Chromecast does not disconnect however after few minutes of sleep, it disconnects as well as, kill the app as well. How can I retain the Chromecast play session even if the device goes to sleep or goes to background.

As I am using `GCKUICastButton` so I am not using the GCKDeviceManager so I am unable to use the ignoreAppStateNotification using GCKDeviceManager, can you advice if I can use that as well.

I have also added the GCKCastOption code as well in AppDelegate.

Comment: are you get the any delegate method `deviceDidComeOnline` in `GCKDevice` its under with in `GCKDeviceScannerListener`

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik no, I did not try this. I will try this and will get back to you.

Comment: in here you need to connect your device again

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.